# JavaScript class properties not available in onclick method

Tags: javascript

Every time that I click the canvas that is created with this code, it always says that `this.element` is undefined when it clearly has been created. The graph that I am displaying is showing up, that is not the problem. If I replace `this.element` with `document.getElementById(id)`, the code will work as intended. Any help or explanation is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
function DrawableChart(id){

    // get canvas
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    this.ctx = this.element.getContext("2d");

    // set data
    this.data = {...};

    // special options
    this.options = {...};

    // create chart
    this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx).Line(this.data, this.options);

    // updating chart
    this.update = function(e){
        // this is where the error is
        console.log(this.element);
        // this line also causes an error
        var rect = this.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    };

    // update when clicked
    this.element.addEventListener('click', this.update);

}
```

Comment: `this` always refers to the caller of the method. I suspect your error lies beyond the code you've provided

Comment: When you call `.addEventListener`, use `this.update.bind(this)` instead of just `this.update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the `update` method and `this` value. Try changing the following:

```
this.update = function(e){ /*...*/ };
```

to:

```
this.update = function(e){ /*...*/ }.bind(this);
```